# Flutter app with Django backend and google authentication

Tags: django, flutter, google-oauth

i would like to create a flutter app, with social authentication (Facebook & Google) connected to a Django DRF backend.

I could not find any examples for handling the social authentication at the back-end coming from a flutter app, i only found firebase based tutorials.

Any libraries that work this way? in case there aren't, how could i send the required social account from the phone to my backend?
Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use the [Google Auth Library for Ruby](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-ruby) (because you are using Django) and expose a service that wrap the API and consume the google libraries.

With your API created you can create a Provider / BLoC or whatever State Management you use in Flutter using the [Dart Package Http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) to consume your own Django backend API

If you have any trouble using HTTP Dart/flutter package let me now to create and example

Comment: Django is a Python framework, not a Ruby one.